# Was/is anything else major planned for Commander Sela from Star Trek: TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Towards the end of TNG Tasha Yar's daughter [Commander Sela](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sela) has a brief stint as enemy in a few episodes. It always seemed as though they cut her arc off suddenly and without resolution. There are a few novels and such that deal with her more, but I was wondering if anyone knows about any canceled or even coming projects that relate to her? I'm talking major projects like unmade TNG movies and the like.

Comment: Does that include or exclude abandoned but planned story arc within The Next Generation?

Comment: @Borror0, well... It can include this, but I kind of assumed that planned to do more.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there are no upcoming major projects related to her: the entire TNG section of the franchise was scrapped after *Star Trek Nemesis*. The only two aspects of that section of the Star Trek timeline that are still active are licensed novels and [Star Trek Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Online); the latter of which [is struggling](http://hailingfrequency.com/boards/news-and-announcements/star-trek-online-struggles-with-only-100k-subscribers!/?nowap) so I wouldn't expect to see anything major to come of it. However, according to the article you linked:

> In Star Trek Online, Sela survived the supernova of 2387 that eliminated of many of her opponents and cleared the way for her rise to Empress of the Romulan Star Empire before she was exiled for attempting to assassinate the head of the Tal Shiar.

Star Trek isn't like *LOST* or other deeply serial dramas: not every character featured is important or will play a huge role except as an entertaining recurring character. Sela was featured in a few TNG episodes, which is pretty good for a recurring character.

Comment: Well, she was really just a vehicle to bring the actress that played Tasha back sometimes. It just struck me as interesting that all the other major characters in the show had some form of closure, but Yar just got killed 3+ times and left behind a daughter who was a minor PITA once or twice.

Comment: @DampeS8N: Exactly. If they didn't intend for her to beat least somewhat important, it was poor writing. Introducing character that looked exactly like a former important character cannot pass as something minor and worth forgetting.

Comment: @DampeS8N @Borror0 the intent of introducing Sela was to bring Denise Crosby back as as a guest star, which was accomplished: if you read the linked *Memory Alpha* article, Sela was created on spec by Crosby. TNG was not a serial drama: there was no overarching storyline where a character  introduced in one season has a major role to play in some distant future.

Comment: [Because](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hugh) they [never](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Lore) did [that.](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q)

Comment: @DampeS8N Q, Lore, and Hugh were recurring characters, just like Sela. When they wrote the scripts for a season, they made a decision as to what stories to write: there was no TNG Bible written before the show starts a la LOST or Battlestar Galactica. None of the characters were introduced with the expectation that Q would end the series, or that Hugh and Lore would be featured several seasons later. It's basic show-running: the reason Q or Lore came back is because the writers wanted to write a new episode and the actors were available. Sela/Denise Crosby is no different.